# Regular expression to parse [A][B] into A and B

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to separate the following string into a separate lines with regular expression

```
[property1=text1][property2=text2]
```

and the desired result should be

```
property1=text1
property2=text2
```

here is my code

```
string[] attrs = Regex.Split(attr_str, @"\[(.+)\]");
```

Results is incorrect, am probably doing something wrong

[image]

**UPDATE:** after applying the suggested answers. Now it shows spaces and empty string

[image]

Comment: How can we tell it to match only [xxx]. There is no [] or [ ] in the string why was it matching those?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.+` is a greedy match, so it grabs as much as possible.

Use either

```
\[([^]]+)\]
```

or

```
\[(.+?)\]
```

In the first case, matching `]` is not allowed, so "as much as possible" becomes shorter.  The second uses a non-greedy match.

Comment: I tried both approaches but it matches space and empty string. How can we tell it to match only [xxx]. There is no [] or [ ] in the string why was it matching those

Comment: @tcoder: That's because you're using `Regex.Split`.  The stuff between the separators is indeed an empty string.  Use `Match` instead.

Comment: That's my bad. I wondered why the first one I did worked. I just cross-checked it, it used the `.Matches` and not `.Split`. THANKS

Answer (score 4):

Your dot is grabbing the braces as well. You need to exclude braces:

```
\[([^]]+)\]
```

The `[^]]` matches any character except a close brace.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the 'lazy' specifier:

```
Regex.Split(attr_str, @"\[(.+?)\]");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var s = "[property1=text1][property2=text2]";
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @"\[(.+?)\]")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value);
```